# Pasar el valor de un input de html a una variable php

Tags: php, html, html5, input

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Tengo una duda sobre cómo pasar el valor de un input que tengo oculto ya que éste obtiene un valor que le mando a través de un js.

```
<input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="nombre obtenido desde un js">
```

Lo que quiero es que el valor de ese input pasarlo a una variable de php dentro de la misma pagina lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

```
$variable = input nombre;
```

¿Alguien sabe como hacer esto?
Mi página la tengo estructurada así:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="nombre obtenido desde un js">
<?php $variable= "input nombre"    ?>
```

El valor del input es obtenido así:

```
var  inputproducto = document.getElementById("nombre");
inputproducto.value= _nombre;// ese valor ya lo tengo en el js solo se lo 
                                envio al input
```

Comment: Es un formulario que envías?

Comment: hola @Jok realmente no, ya no envio nada solo queria saber si es posible pasar ese value del input a una variable php estan en la misma pagina ambos tanto html y php

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes el valor del input? Puedes poner el código de ese campo?

Comment: llamada con $.ajax o mediante un formulario

Comment: @Jok que tal, ya lo actualize, el input que tengo su value es el resultado de un valor que tengo en el js, ese codigo js solo hace que modifique el value de ese input llamandola por su id en el php. en ese mismo php lo que queria ya aprovechando que pase el valor del js por medio del input, tomarlo para que se le asignara en una variable php que quiero usar en esa pagina.

Comment: @Srsole realmente solo es un input que se rellena por medio de un valor enviado con .value desde el js, solo le modifica el value al input mediante la id, quizas es lo que queria pasar el valor al php aunque por medio del input pero ese value ya no lo puedo usar para mas por que no hallo la forma en que el value se retome en una variable que va en esa misma pagina de php

Comment: @armandosarmiento la unica manera de pasar una variable de HTML(js) a PHP es como te digo.

Comment: No logro entender lo que quieres hacer... ¿por qué o para qué necesitas el valor en una variable de PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Quizá simplemente puedes almacenar el valor desde JS con una cookie y haces la asignación en PHP:

```
<script>
    document.cookie = "variable = " + nombre; //Este es el que estás ya obteniendo vía JS
</script>

<?php
     $variable= $_COOKIE['variable'];
?>
```

De esta forma lo consigues rápidamente, espero sea lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que entiendo lo que necesitas, pero no es necesario usar PHP, solo JS. Si quieres usar el valor del input hidden en otros controles, un código como este te puede bastar:

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
      var inputproducto = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
      var caract_1 = document.getElementById("caract_1");
      var caract_2 = document.getElementById("caract_2");
        caract_1.value= inputproducto;
        caract_2.innerHTML = inputproducto;
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ejemplo Imput hidden y JS</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="nombre obtenido desde un js">
<input type="text" name="caract_1" id="caract_1" value="">
<p id="caract_2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Fíjate que el JS manda el valor a otras partes del documento.